# Indian citizen transiting in Dubai, is a transit visa required?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, dxb

I am an Indian citizen travelling to Muscat from USA via Dubai. To Dubai by United Airlines via Zurich. Six hours later from Dubai by flydubai.

Since it is a separate booking, do I require a transit visa for Dubai?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Airline transit passengers travelling with a stopover at Dubai Airport (or other UAE airport) who do not leave the terminal building, do not need a UAE visa since they are not entering the UAE. "

Taken from http://www.dubaifaqs.com/visa-transit-dubai.php

Moreover "Transit passengers stopping at Dubai International Airport for a minimum of 8 hours and meeting certain conditions mentioned below are eligible for obtaining a 96-hour transit visa."

from http://www.uae.org.br/Ingles/Consular/transvisa.htm

So technically you CANNOT and therefore need not apply for a transit visa

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. I'm arriving to Dubai via Swiss airline to Terminal 1 and My Fly Dubai flight is from Terminal 2 after 4 hours. I guess i'll need a transit visa in that case, Am I correct?

Comment: @user3044327 edit your question to indicate this please, this point does matter